# Do all files under recipes section get execute in chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Do all the files under recipes section will be loaded when we execute 'chef-client' on the client  node or else we have to add dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

General note: when you have a series of questions like this it might be easier to jump on IRC or Slack and ask directly.

No, while all files under `attributes/` and `libraries/` get loaded during setup, only the recipes you put on the run list get executed (or recipes that are run indirectly from those via `include_recipe`). You can find details of the loading process at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/.

Comment: Yay! I made you 10k. Thanks mate. Useful Doc.